# The drush command 'sql dump' could not be found

Tags: drush

Im a trying to do a backup of my drupal site with:

```
drush -v sql dump --result-file=DrupalBackups/nameofsqldb5.sql
```

but it results in following error message:

```
The drush command 'sql dump' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to 
[error] clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.
```

I ran drush cache-clear drush but without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual command is `sql-dump` not `sql dump`

```
drush -v sql-dump --result-file=DrupalBackups/nameofsqldb5.sql
```

From `drush help`:

> sql-dump              Exports the Drupal DB as SQL using mysqldump or
>   equivalent.

Comment: OP is asking another question.

Comment: Which other question? If you need a sql dump the command is 'sql-dump' no 'sql dump'.

Comment: yes, i read it wrong.

Comment: thank you! https://drupaltraining.stanford.edu/node/85  I guess stanford needs to update there training then ;)